# How can I adjust position of SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to set SVG right but I didn't succeed with `right: 0;` Transform, positioning is often quite difficult in such cases, I don't know which one to choose.

What positioning settings are used for SVG? Also I would appreciate if you recommend useful sites for SVG.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.page-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 80vh;
}

.custom-shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-shape svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
  height: 121px;
}

.custom-shape .shape-fill {
  fill: #EC2424;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-1">
  <div class="custom-shape">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path d="M0,0V46.29c47.79,22.2,103.59,32.17,158,28,70.36-5.37,136.33-33.31,206.8-37.5C438.64,32.43,512.34,53.67,583,72.05c69.27,18,138.3,24.88,209.4,13.08,36.15-6,69.85-17.84,104.45-29.34C989.49,25,1113-14.29,1200,52.47V0Z" opacity=".25" class="shape-fill"></path>
      <path d="M0,0V15.81C13,36.92,27.64,56.86,47.69,72.05,99.41,111.27,165,111,224.58,91.58c31.15-10.15,60.09-26.07,89.67-39.8,40.92-19,84.73-46,130.83-49.67,36.26-2.85,70.9,9.42,98.6,31.56,31.77,25.39,62.32,62,103.63,73,40.44,10.79,81.35-6.69,119.13-24.28s75.16-39,116.92-43.05c59.73-5.85,113.28,22.88,168.9,38.84,30.2,8.66,59,6.17,87.09-7.5,22.43-10.89,48-26.93,60.65-49.24V0Z" opacity=".5" class="shape-fill"></path>
      <path d="M0,0V5.63C149.93,59,314.09,71.32,475.83,42.57c43-7.64,84.23-20.12,127.61-26.46,59-8.63,112.48,12.24,165.56,35.4C827.93,77.22,886,95.24,951.2,90c86.53-7,172.46-45.71,248.8-84.81V0Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to set `right: 0` on? There's no `right: 0` in your example.

Comment: It would help if you described what you are actually trying to achieve. It is not very clear from your question.

Comment: @Sean I want svg to be placed to the right of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly the result you require from your code example, but some things to take into consideration...

### SVG styling

- Default SVG display CSS is `inline`, but you have already changed this to `block` which is perfect so it behaves like a DIV now.
- Default SVG ratio abides by the `viewBox` attribute settings, so what ever the `width` or `height` CSS you set on the SVG elem, the SVG aspect ratio will be fixed based on the `viewBox` value.
- Possibly (cannot remember for certain) if you set both `width` and `height` CSS, this may override `viewBox` ratio settings and force the SVG to what ever you define.
- Obviously any inline CSS attributes like `width` or `height` may possibly override any stylesheet CSS you set.
- You have set attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` so `viewBox` settings will be ignored.

### SVG positioning

- SVG element `<svg>` positioning behaviour is pretty much exactly like positioning any other element html based on which ever CSS `display` mode or `position` you define.
- SVG inner child elements (`path`, `rect`, `circle`, etc) are positioned absolute (relative to the SVG elem), using inline attributes like `d` or prefixed `x`/`y`.
- Ideally never try override child SVG element positioning with CSS unless you truly understand their position behaviour.
- When you position SVG elements directly, the ratio will stay true to the `viewBox` settings unless you are forcing otherwise.

### A few SVG browser CSS quirks

- When targeting SVG elements and child elements in your CSS, it is full proof practice to target them by a `class`, `id` or `data` attribute.
- Mainly iOS safari does not recognise targeting child SVG elements by element name, for example `SVG PATH { fill: blue; }` with have some issues in safari/mobile, and maybe other browsers. The way you used `class="shape-fill"` on your `<path>` is perfect  .
- Might be worth switching the way you target `.custom-shape svg` by targeting the SVG directly with an `id` or `class` selector, just to be certain.
- I think targeting the actual SVG parent element the way you have in your example might behave ok on iOS, but worth testing on all desktop and mobile browsers to be sure.. especially the older IE's before Edge if you require them.

For SVG reference, the bible for SVG is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

---

If you want further help with your example code in your question, please elaborate more detail in your question to fix your problem.

> Also why are you adding `1.3px` to the SVG `100%` width?

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to move some SVG text in the chrome browser and i am mentioning my code below

```
text.identity{
  transform: translate(74px,0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Opera */
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

i hope

Comment: Thanks bro but it didn't

Comment: This code is unrelated to the code in the example.